# Word file becomes corrupted if I add a .docx extension?

Tags: ms-word, format, docx, corruption

I have this file, which I did not create.
It opens flawlessly when I open it with as "Open With" in Windows 7.
It also opens flawlessly when I launch Word, and open it from Word.
However if I add a .docx extension to the file and double click on it, it doe snot open and the error message states it is corrupted.
Can you please explain me why?

Comment: It probably isn't in the format that Word expects a `docx` file to be.  What type of file is it?  And what is its extension before you try to change it?

Comment: It has no extension.

Comment: What sort of file is it?  Is it a text file?  Is it a Word ".doc" file?  Is it a Word ".docm" file?  Is it a Rich Text Format file?  (And are you sure it has no extension, or do you just have extensions hidden for known file types?)

Comment: If you aren't sure what type it is, you may be able to find out by opening it and then doing a "Save As" - it should default to saving it in the format that it thinks it opened as, so that dialog should show you what that was.

Comment: Extension are not hidden in explorer. It is simply a file without extension that is generated by JIRA, and which is supposed to be opened by Word. I simply do not understand at all why it would not open if I added a .docx extension while it opens using the two other methods described above.

Comment: Adding a specific extension makes Word thinks it is in the format associated with the extension, and gets upset if it isn't in that format.  Without an extension (or with an unknown extension) Word has to guess what format it is - and is obviously guessing correctly.

Comment: I see. When I add a .doc extension, it opens correctly with a double click. Only .docx does not open. Can Word not realise it is a .doc even if the extension is .docx? Sounds a bit retarded.

Comment: `doc` files are completely different format to `docx` - e.g. `docx` files are just many `xml` files ZIPped into one file, but `doc` files are in a Microsoft proprietary format.  Reading the two would use completely different methods.  If you tell it is a `docx`, it isn't going to think you are lying to it - it's going to think the file is corrupted.

Comment: I understand, thanks!

Comment: there is more to it because Word can open docx format files that have .doc extension (with a warning message). The only reason I can think of is because docx format files can't contain macros, but doc can